# Loop through string get key and value using regex key matches Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have a string like

```
> var temp =
> "meta(alias:!n,apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:'index_*',key:stockInfo.raw,negate:!f,value:green),"
```

For information, this string is generated automatically by kibana (I recover it through the url).

My question is :
There is any solutions to extract keys and values from this string and get a result in a array or an object like this :

```
>  var result = { 
>                  "alias" : "!n",
>                  "apply" : "!t",
>                  "disabled" : "!f",
>                  "key": "stockInfo.raw",
>                  "negate": "!f",
>                  "value": "green",  
>               }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're searching something like this:

```js
var meta = "meta(alias:!n,apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:'index_*',key:stockInfo.raw,negate:!f,value:green),"

var result = {}

meta.substr(0, meta.length - 2).substr(5).split(',').forEach(function(item) {
  var split = item && item.split(':')
  if (split.length) {
    result[split[0]] = split[1];
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Split the string by `,` character and then split by `:` to identify key and value of object

Answer (score 1):

same as other but with some es6 syntax :D

```js
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const input = document.getElementById("input");

// string: data from url, return only the portion from the parenthesis
const extract_meta_values = string => {
 const EXTRACTOR = /^meta\(([^\)]+)\)/g;
 return EXTRACTOR.exec(string)[1];
}

// string: is a string of key:values separated by a comma
const meta_values_to_array_of_objects = string => string.split(',').map( tuple => {
  const [key, value] = tuple.split(':');
  return { [key]: value };
});

const meta_values = extract_meta_values(input.value);
const final = meta_values_to_array_of_objects(meta_values);

// print out
result.innerText = JSON.stringify(final, null, 2);
```

```css
pre {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<p>
<input value="meta(alias:!n,apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:'index_*',key:stockInfo.raw,negate:!f,value:green)," id=input />
</p>

<pre id=result></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring to within parenthesis, split by comma, loop through, split by colon and add to an object.

```js
var temp = "meta(alias:!n,apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:'index_*',key:stockInfo.raw,negate:!f,value:green)";
var t = {};
temp
  .substr(temp.indexOf("(") + 1, temp.indexOf(")") - temp.indexOf("(") - 1)
  .split(",")
  .forEach(function(a) {
    var b = a.split(":");
    t[b[0]] = b[1];
  });
console.log(t);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. ^^